# Login provider with own login screen

Tags: cordova, authentication, cloudboost

I am developing a cordova application with `CloudBoost` and it requires own login page.

I decided to use `ng-cordova-oauth` plugin to get the `access_token` from the providers. After getting the token, it is called the function to login the user in the CloudBoost system.

**In every request made to login the user, it is returned : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" loginwithprovider (0,0).**

This message is obtained after receiving the access_token from the provider.

> Is it related with the format of the token?

Example of the login funcion used on facebook.

```
$scope.login_facebook = function ()
{

  $cordovaOauth.facebook("XXX", ["email", "public_profile"]).then(function (result) 
     {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        CB.CloudUser.authenticateWithProvider({
            provider: "facebook",
            accessToken: result.access_token
        }, {
            success: function (user) {
                console.log(user);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
   });
}
```